# Getting 8010 event id with SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-SharePoint Products-Document Management Server
Date:          5/16/2017 11:32:03 PM
Event ID:      8010
Task Category: Content Organizer
Level:         Error
Keywords:      
User:          Domain\username
Computer:      Server name
Description:
Content Organizer processing for site http://Server/sites/Site collection name/subsitename(Url) encountered an error.

Error:  System.ArgumentException: EmailSubmittedRecordsListID
   at Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.Internal.Utility.UniqueListManager.GetList(String strSaveName, SPWeb webSaveLocation, Boolean fThrowIfNotFound, Ids messageOnError)
   at Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.RecordsRepository.EcmDocumentRoutingWeb.get_IsEmailRoutingEnabled()
   at Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.Internal.RecordsRepositoryJobDefinition.<>c__DisplayClass3.<ProcessSite>b__1(SPWeb web)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.CultureUtility.RunWithCultureScope(CodeToRunWithCultureScope code)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.ContentIterator.ProcessSite(SPSite site, Boolean fSetThreadCulture, WebProcessor webProcessor, WebProcessorErrorCallout errorCallout)
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-SharePoint Products-Document Management Server" Guid="{F78D66EC-09A9-42A2-AC7A-5EE2062DE7E4}" />
    <EventID>8010</EventID>
    <Version>15</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>7</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-05-17T03:32:03.251270100Z" />
    <EventRecordID>3510178</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{336AF29D-89F5-102D-A325-5E84E83924B4}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="9172" ThreadID="11504" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Server name</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-3672398596-3227583511-885490141-1119996" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="string0">http://Server/sites/Site collection name/subsitename(Url)</Data>
    <Data Name="string1">System.ArgumentException: EmailSubmittedRecordsListID
   at Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.Internal.Utility.UniqueListManager.GetList(String strSaveName, SPWeb webSaveLocation, Boolean fThrowIfNotFound, Ids messageOnError)
   at Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.RecordsRepository.EcmDocumentRoutingWeb.get_IsEmailRoutingEnabled()
   at Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.Internal.RecordsRepositoryJobDefinition.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass3.&lt;ProcessSite&gt;b__1(SPWeb web)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.CultureUtility.RunWithCultureScope(CodeToRunWithCultureScope code)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.ContentIterator.ProcessSite(SPSite site, Boolean fSetThreadCulture, WebProcessor webProcessor, WebProcessorErrorCallout errorCallout)</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

PLease help me how to fix this issue?

Comment: could you please add more details about the issue, how this error occurred and what action causing this? i am afraid may be this marked as low quality.

Comment: Daily we are receiving the alerts hence started looking into it.

Comment: Check the ULS logs for that time stamp. also are u using word automation service?

Comment: yes we are using but it is causing for particular sub site and I can see there we have Info path farms is that causing issue?

Comment: just add ur findings in your question, so others can understand and try to help u

Comment: I will add today waqas sarwar!

Comment: Getting 8010 error on particular subsite with front end server.

Comment: Please refer the below URL for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the below URL for answer.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d60796d-a21f-4580-817f-ea5f33aff27c/unexpected-error-when-clicking-content-organizer-settings-in-site-administration?forum=sharepointadminprevious&prof=required